# using jQuery html() doesn't retain css?

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following html ([fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/7NM2j/1/))

```
 <div class="thumbnail_follow" id="follow_btn-2">
   <a  class="btn btn-primary" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Follow</a>
 </div>
```

upon clicking on the button, I want the button to replace itself with an unfollow button with the html of

```
  <div class="thumbnail_follow" id="follow_btn-2">
<a href="/users/2/unfollow" class="btn btn-danger" data-method="post" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">Unfollow</a>
</div>
```

So basically, change the button and the link which it points to

I use jQuery html() like this

```
 $("#follow_btn-2").html('<a class=\"btn btn-danger\" data-method=\"post\" data-remote=\"true\" rel=\"nofollow\">Unfollow<\/a>');
```

note this is generated via rails ujs from the code

```
$("div[id='follow_btn-<%= @user.id %>']").html('<%=j link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_user_path(@user), :remote => true, :method => :post , :class=>"btn btn-danger"%>');
```

the problem, as visible from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NM2j/1/), is that once the button is replaced with the red one, it jumps away as if its style got messed up..

I don't understand what is causing the jump and how to fix it.. Is it a css problem or a bad jQuery usage?

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7NM2j/1/) once more

Comment: You are certainly making this hard for yourself, instead of replacing the button completely, why not change the attributes with `.attr()`?

Comment: And if you can, find a way to stop using `!important` - it is generally not required. See http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase width of container to properly fit your button.

```
width: 200px !important;
```

Your red button has more width then your blue button

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/7NM2j/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Its because Follow is shorter than Unfollow and your container (thumbnail_car) is to small.